# UICollectionView cannot scroll to the end

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to build a custom scroll tab bar liking the following. 
[image: scroll tab bar]

My first step is to build a UICollectionView filled with UIlabel. However, when I scroll the items, the UICollectionView cannot reach the end (see the following picture). Apparently,there are still some items left. If I drag the view, it will show the left items. But once I released my mouse, it will scroll back to the following state.

By the away, I am new iOS programmer, and trying to build a custom scroll tab bar like the gif shows, I don't know which is better for this case, UIScrollView or UICollectionView?

my Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var xdTabBar: UICollectionView!


let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    // self.xdTabBar.contentSize = CGSize(width: (50+10)*50, height: 70)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
    return 1
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
    // println(array.count)
    return array.count

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ScrollableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! XDCollectionViewCell

    cell.title.text = "\(indexPath.item)"
    return cell
}
```

}

[image: cannot reach end]

Comment: This is obviously a swift question, not an Objective-C question. Fix your tags.